# bsd-mailx doesn't add From header which fails with libopendkim

Tags: linux, email, dkim

We are using Plesk Onyx 17.0.17 with Postfix on a Debian Jessie server and have activated DKIM via Plesk. When I try to send a mail as root from the shell, this leads to the following error in maillog:

```
echo "" | mail -s "test DKIM" jondoe@example.com

Jul  7 11:20:56 myserver dk_sign[5892]: DKIM error: DKIM Feed: Syntax error
Jul  7 11:20:56 myserver plesk sendmail[5889]: Error during 'dd51-domainkeys' handler
```

According to the Plesk support, `bsd-mailx` doesn't add a From header which leads to `libopendkim` failing, and this could be circumvented by adding `-a "From: postmaster@myserver.net"`.

This works for the moment, but will most certainly lead to problems with scripts or other programs using `bsd-mailx`. I searched a lot, but couldn't find other users with this problem, while I think there should be. So either, I am the only one with this problem or there is a solution I don't know yet...

Comment: Plesk support: "This software issue has been confirmed as bug ID PPPM-6690". Now I am waiting for a fix. No release date yet...

Comment: Plesk has released an article on this bug: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002513925-Email-messages-are-not-signed-with-DKIM-if-they-are-sent-from-PHP-scripts